# React - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to load a ReactJS component on a razor page. I have my App.jsx file and i parse it in a App.js file with Babel. So the next step should be to import it in the razor page as a tag like '' but when i run the project the page is blank and the inspector's console throw: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined'.
I searched a lot and think that the problem is the browser?but testing with opera and chrome i have the same result.
Maybe my project's settings are not valide to use module?Cause for other test, if i tried to import a componenent Child to app it fail due to import that cannot be used.
**If i have forgotten any important files, please let me know**

App.jsx:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { message: 'Hello, World!' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

App.js:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: 'Hello, World!'
    };
  }
  render() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, this.state.message));
  }
}
var _default = App;
exports.default = _default;
```

index.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/build/App.js")" ></script>

<App></App>
```

babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "60",
          "chrome": "67",
          "safari": "11.1",
          "opera": "54"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.6.5"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel SportData.Web/wwwroot/js --out-dir SportData.Web/wwwroot/js/build --presets @babel/preset-react"
  }
}
```

import js file in the Program.cs:

```
app.UseReact(config => {
            config.AddScript("~/js/build/App.js");
        });
```

Comment: what do you think `exports` should be? that's not a *thing* in the browser, so the browser isn't "broken", the code is

Comment: And how can i change the jsx or js file in order to be render as a component? The main question is, how can i make sure my project can export component? If the code if wrong, how can i fix it? Cause if you want to use a Component in a page, the App.jsx file is the basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding in _Layout.cshtml `<script>var exports = {};</script>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).